# Understanding a C macro with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, macros

I am a Java developer, I am not very familiar with the syntax of C macros. I am studying on Deitel & Deitel book, but it does not help.

I can't understand the meaning of this macro:

```
#define _GetFrontItem(d,q)  ( (d)->itemCache + ( (q)*(d)->block_size +  \
                              (d)->offset[q] % (d)->block_size )*(d)->itemSize)
```

`d` is a pointer to a struct, `q` is a `size_t`.

The macro is used [in this file](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~demetres/didattica/ae/wikka.php?wakka=LFileSortC).

Can you please help me understand it? What does this macro accomplish? Why is it written in the way it is written? Is there a more clear way to write this macro?

Comment: What *exactly* is it that you don't understand?

Comment: `d` should be a **pointer** to a **struct** NOT a struct !!

Comment: @Meninx you are right. I fixed it.

Comment: @nvoigt The following things I can't understand. What does this macro accomplish? Why is it written in the way it is written? Is there a more clear way to write this macro?

Comment: Read here https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/PRE01-C.+Use+parentheses+within+macros+around+parameter+names This should make you clear why there are so many parantheses. The \ character is needed if you need to break down long macro definition into several lines (and yes, it's for readability). In general macros in C can be tricky to use, as argument may be evaluated more than once within its expansion.

Comment: @WeatherVane so if it was rewritten as an inline function it could be as efficient as this macro?

Comment: [Useful information for us](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~demetres/didattica/ae/wikka.php?wakka=LFileSortC).

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but at the time of macro resolution there is no such thing as types.

Comment: Without knowing more about the data structure that's in use and how it stores value, etc, it is not easy to see what the macro is doing or why it is written like that.  With the larger context, it might be clearer.  The macro is badly named; names starting with an underscore and capital letter are reserved for 'the implementation' and should only be used by those creating the runtime libraries used to support C, not by ordinary users.

Comment: @WeatherVane The question does not call for speculation about who is likely to write this sort of code, so please spare us yours.

Comment: @WeatherVane: for instance take a look at the macrodefinition for `getc()` :: it is even more complex. (but it works, apparently)

Comment: @WeatherVane Anything from “An academic might …” if your **comment** (which you know full well is not an answer as you didn't post it as such) is speculation based on prejudice and hubris.

Comment: @WeatherVane `getc()` takes one argument (the input file stream) which is (in all cases that I know of) is also a macro (stdin resolves to (&_iobuf[0]) IIRC). The amount of work done to maintain the flags, the offset, the pushback buffer and the main buffer is a multiple of the *trivial* code in the OQ)

Comment: @WeatherVane Again, your opinions about what you call academics are irrelevant. If you have an explanation about the code in the question, post it. The fact that you have an engineering background and what you think of what you call academics is off-topic here.

Comment: @wildplasser yes it does, sorry, but I don't know what you are trying to prove by pointing out the existence of a more complex macro, apart from that you think this question is *trivial*.

Comment: Yes, it is trivial. `(q)` is used to compute some offset scaled by some blocksize; only the modulo `(d)->offset[q] % (d)->block_size )` looks rather strange.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski The argument about security is mute with this macro: the macro, as it is, is not safe. It evaluates `d` five times and `q` twice. As such, it would have been more honest to leave off the parentheses around the arguments and add a big, fat warning comment... But, of course, it should have been a `static` function in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

whenever you write  `_GetFrontItem(d,q)` in your source code it will be replaced by the **preprocessor** into this line

```
(d)->itemCache + ( (q)*(d)->block_size + (d)->offset[q] % (d)->block_size )*(d)->itemSize
```

so here the `d` must be a **pointer** of a structure by noticing the `->`.
Morever the structure pointed by `d` must have **at least 3 members** as follows  `itemCache`, `block_size` and an array called `offset` of data type

This macro does nothing but replacing a calculation.

Another thing, in the first line:

`#define _GetFrontItem(d,q)  ( (d)->itemCache + ( (q)*(d)->block_size +`    **`\`**

notice the antislash `\` at the end of the line. This character when used when defining the macro (at the end of the line of course)  will let you continue writing on the second line as if you continued it in the first line. It can be considered as a tool to make the code readable and not complicated !!

Comment: Thanks! One more thing: I saw that itemCache is an array, can I rewrite the macro using [] instead of pointer arithmetics?

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij, yes pointers can be indexed *or* arithmiticized (my word :))

Answer (score 6):

I have to say, that is a damn ugly macro. Moving on.

What the macro does is compute an index into the struct's "item cache" (whatever that is), and returns a pointer to it : `(d->itemCache + something)` is equivalent to `&d->itemCache[something]`.

The macro is thus equivalent to the following inline function (identifiers sweeped from a google match [here](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~demetres/didattica/ae/wikka.php?wakka=LFileSortC)) :

```
static inline char *_GetFrontItem(Data *d, size_t q) {
    return &d->itemCache[
        d->itemSize * (q * d->block_size + d->offset[q] % d->block_size)
    ];
}
```

... which is a bit more intelligible. Why it is a macro in the first place is probably because this is legacy code, from the old times when inline functions simply didn't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about the existence of inline functions!

Comment: The direct replacement would be like `static inline` function. I think there is no need to throw it as external symbol (as `extern` storage-class is taken by default).

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski absolutely. Edited, thank you !

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij in modern (as in, past 1990) pogramming, functions should always be preferred to macros, except if you really want to use macro magic (generating code, synthesizing identifiers, the like). An inline function will produce the exact same code as a macro, except it's legible and type-safe.

Comment: Also note that `inline` is not needed if `static` is present: With `static` the compiler knows about *all* uses of the function, and thus can make an informed decision about whether to inline or not. That decision is likely to be better than the choice of a programmer who uses the `inline` keyword without profiling first. Inlining is a double edged sword, too much of it can make your program *slower*, so better trust the compiler to make a wise decision or profile; don't just add `inline` wherever you can.

Answer (score 3):

In this case `d` is a pointer to a struct object. That struct object contains a buffer `d->itemCache` (most likely an array of `unsigned char`s). The buffer actually represents an array of larger objects, each object consisting of `d->itemSize` bytes. So, in order to obtain a pointer to object number `i` in this array you have to evaluate the following expression

```
d->itemCache + i * d->itemSize
```

That is exactly what your macro does, except that element index `i` is evaluated through parameter `q` as

```
q * d->block_size + d->offset[q] % d->block_size
```

This is probably determined by the specifics of the data structure in question.

In order to make this macro a bit more readable one can split it into several macros

```
#define _GetItem(d, i)  ((d)->itemCache + (i) * (d)->itemSize)
#define _GetFrontIndex(d, q) ((q) * (d)->block_size + (d)->offset[q] % (d)->block_size)
#define _GetFrontItem(d, q) _GetItem(d, _GetFrontIndex(d, q))
```